# How do I enable hardware accelerated video in VLC with Intel HD 4000 GPU?

Tags: intel-graphics, vlc, hd-video, vaapi

I am running Ubuntu 12.10 on a Dell Latitude E5530, and I am unable to get hardware accelerated video decoding running in VLC player.

I've ticked the hardware acceleration option in the settings of VLC, installed all `libva`, `libdrm` and `vaapi` related packages, yet the CPU usage indicates me it's still not active. The CPU usage during the playback of a 720p video is 40-80%, where I would expect to see a lot lower usage on my machine.

Can anyone give me some advice on how to get it working?

The output of vainfo is:

```
libva: VA-API version 0.32.0
libva: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva: va_openDriver() returns 0
vainfo: VA-API version: 0.32 (libva 1.0.15)
vainfo: Driver version: Intel i965 driver - 1.0.17
vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
      VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264Baseline           : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264Baseline           : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileVC1Simple              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Main                : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Advanced            : VAEntrypointVLD
```

I've tried to play 720p mpg, mp4 and wmv movies, yet none of them ran hardware accelerated.

The codecs of the tested movies are:

- mpeg: H264-MPEG 4-AVC (part 10) (avc) (resulting 80% CPU usage, full HD resolution)
- mp4: MPEG 4 Video (mp4v) (16% CPU usage, 720p)
- wmv: Windows Media Video 7 (WMV1) (16 % CPU usage, 720p resolution)

Taking a look at System Monitor, I can see, that all four CPU threads (talking about a i5-3210M dual-core processor) are nearly equally stressed, so the above mentioned 16 and 80% CPU usage is distributed among the threads).

Comment: For those interested: [a solution for **NVIDIA** video cards](http://askubuntu.com/questions/834997/how-to-enable-hardware-acceleration/848945#848945).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> ## VA-API (Hardware Acceleration For Intel )

[Is there a power saving application similar to Jupiter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/jupiter-or-similar-power-saving-app-for-13-04/285681#285681) check my answer for full detail

#### for Intel GPUs (for Intel HD Graphics as well as G45 and later):

```
 sudo apt-get install i965-va-driver libva-intel-vaapi-driver vainfo
```

> ### Configuration

**VLC**

Its in Tools > Preferences > Input & Codecs > Enable **Use GPU Accelerated decoding**

[image]

[How to correctly enable/test VA-API on Intel Sandy Bridge?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247911/how-to-correctly-enable-test-va-api-on-intel-sandy-bridge)

```
 vlc --ffmpeg-hw -v
```

Check the line

```
 [0x7fd018c02d38] avcodec decoder: Using VA API version 0.32 for hardware decoding.
```

Comment: I have installed the 3 packages and activated GPU decoding. On Intel HD 3000, for a 720hd movie my processor usage was 12-13% before activating this and 6% after. Great job!

Comment: VLC now has dropdown for "Hardware-accelerated decoding" setting, only "VA-API video decoder via DRM" and "... via X11" worked for me, default "Automatic" option doesn't work. Also, there is no "--ffmeg-hw" option anymore. Care to update your answer?

Comment: I will check the issue and if i find anything ill update it. Thanks for the update @Suor

Comment: In VLC 2.1.3 the option is: --avcodec-hw=vaapi. Hope it helps someone.