# Playing GoPro video in Linux

Tags: video, vlc, totem

I have 1080p 60fps video that I took with my GoPro Hero4 and want to play on my linux desktop.

When I try to use Totem to watch the videos, it always plays them in slow motion and the sound cuts out after watching for 3 seconds.  If I move haead to another point in the video, the sound starts again but then cuts out.

When I use VLC player, the sound works properly, but the video is so choppy and pixelated it is unwatchable.

These issues occur whether I watch the videos from my PC hard drive or portable hard drive.

Do I need to install new video drivers?  I have an old Dell Vostro 1710, so it is possible that something is out of date.

Edit: I dual boot with Windows 7, and the videos play great with WMP.

Answer (score 1):

This turns out to be a hassle in some cases using an old LTS Ubuntu.  You may find the following command line useful

```
ffmpeg -i MyVideoIn.mp4 -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -r 25 -s xga -c:a copy OutputVideo.mkv
```

This will considerably downgrade the video and take some time.  It sets the frame rate to 25; 30 might be better but in my case I needed 25.  In the end though, the output video works and solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should enable gpu decoding using this guide [How do I enable hardware accelerated video in VLC with Intel HD 4000 GPU?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/240386/how-do-i-enable-hardware-accelerated-video-in-vlc-with-intel-hd-4000-gpu) and see if that helps it really helped with my netbook a dell mini 1012

Comment: His Dell Vostro does not have an Intel HD GPU, it has a much older Intel GMA X3100 - I'd be surprised if it did hardware video decode.

Answer (score 0):

You have a 9 year old single-core mobile Celeron CPU.  It's likely that it's just not powerful enough to support h.264 at 1080P 60fps.

The symptoms you describe do imply this to be the case.

If so, there is no easy way to play these in their current format without updating to a modern CPU.

You could:

- Record at a lower frame rate or resolution
- Transcode to a lower frame rate or resolution for playback later (this will be VERY slow if done on your laptop)
- Try messing with decode settings in VLC, primarily disable "in-loop deblocking" - however this WILL visibly degrade picture quality.

Comment: I have a dual boot with Windows 7.  Windows Media Player works perfectly, so I find it hard to believe that my CPU is incapable of playing the video.

Comment: That rules out your CPU being too slow then.  You may want to add that information to your question.